# Login using Google auth - open in new tab (or open default browser in electron)

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I am following this [google API docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference?hl=en) to login on web apps (without going through backend)

I am on this:

```
const GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
GoogleAuth.signIn();
```

and my `gapi.init/gapi.load` looks like this:

```
      gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: clientId,
          scope: scope.join(' '),
          ux_mode: 'redirect',
          redirect_uri: '<my reirect uri>',
        });
      });
```

without `ux_mode=redirect` and `redirect_uri` this code works and opens a popup, however I'm on an electron app and popup is not allowed by google. I can't change the user agent as well (because it would produce some issues for us on other stuff).

Adding `ux_mode=redirect` would redirect the electron screen to the google page, and I don't want this, I want it so it will open the default web browser instead (I have a webpage that handles web protocol and stuff).

Any ideas?

Comment: OAuth flow should be be you send the user to google, they authenticate (in the same window) then they return that use back to your web page. That way there is no way for your web page to ever have access to their credentials

Comment: I guess I'll have to do a the webserver one for this then: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

so I can pass the credentials to the electron app.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error that you are getting.

Comment: The consent screen must open on the default browser of the machine running the code.   Remember the access token is only going to be good for an hour thats a lot of passing tokens around.

Comment: @DaImTo I am not getting any errors. I just want it to open a new tab instead of redirecting/opening a popup because google is blocking electron apps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66769003/how-can-i-use-google-sign-in-inside-of-an-electron-desktop-application

Comment: @IamL how does your question differ from the one you just linked? Seems like that could be a duplicate.

Comment: @DaImTo Sorry for the confusion, My question is "How to open in new tab using google javascript auth api", the one I linked is on how to handle electron login - the user there is using google web-server api.